# CSS min-height 100% not applying when content overflows

Tags: html, css

I have the following css to make the background cover 100% of the screen, dynamically when the page is re-sized.

```
html { 
     height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

which works fine until the content which is dynamic overflows, the background doesn't then increase with the added content, so i'm left with white space at the the bottom of the page.

An artists impression:
[image: normal size browser]
**- normal sized browser**

[image: resized browser]
**- resized browser**

any suggestions with what i'm doing wrong or what i need to do to make it fill the screen to 100% when the content overflows either due to content or browser size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Remove the rule: `height: 100%;` from the html selector

2) Add `background-attachment: fixed;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/um62xoqm/3/)**

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/1000");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you, without the background-attachment: fixed; this didn't work for when the content didn't reach the full screen height. removing the html height and adding the background-attachment to the body works a treat